# Parameters of the request of a form not sent

Tags: html, forms

I have a problem with this form, no matter which method I use (POST or GET), it doesn't send the request parameters `email` and `pass`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="controller/connect_user.php" method="GET">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" required>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" required>
        <button type="submit">Connect</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem doesn't come from the adress in action, the file is well referenced.

I know I shouldn't use GET for sensitive data, but I used this method because it allows me to see easily the parameters in the URL.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `name` attribute to pass data like this:

```
<form action="controller/connect_user.php" method="GET">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" required>
    <button type="submit">Connect</button>
```

instead of this:

```
<form action="controller/connect_user.php" method="GET">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required>
    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" required>
    <button type="submit">Connect</button>
</form>
```

After you can get thhose values like this:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

I recommend to you to use `POST` instead of `GET`

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your inputs a name:

```
<form action="controller/connect_user.php" method="GET">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
      <label for="pass">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit">Connect</button>
</form>
```

Then, in your PHP you can access them like:

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

A input needs a name-attribute, otherwise there is no possiblity to get it (through GET or POST)

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required>
```